# How to convert IOB to Conll U?

Tags: converters, named-entity-recognition, conll

I am trying to convert a simple IOB file to Conll U, since the model I am trying to use requires Conll U format. Is there a simple and fast way to do so? The file looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a utility, or a language to write a converter in, or a library for a particular language that might do it?

Comment: I can do a little bit of python and a little bit of Java. But I would rather have a library or a converter, that can convert the data to conll u